# Counting the terms of a list using an inequality involving itself

Tags: list-manipulation

How do i count the elements in a list that is between half the *n*'th term and *n*'th term
for example, I have the list:
`{2,3,5,9,13,14,23,27,41,67,81,99}`,
and I want:
`{0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2}`.
what would be the code for this?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, try to do it for one :`Count[list, _?(14/2 < # < 14 &)]` then generalize to all elements using `/@` like `(x |-> Count[list, _?(x/2 < # < x &)]) /@ list`. Notice that the second time I used a function I used `|->` instead of `#`. Often when I want to use functions twice and I do not want me or the computer to get confused I use `#` and `x|->`. Maybe it is not always necessary but I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {2, 3, 5, 9, 13, 14, 23, 27, 41, 67, 81, 99};

Cases[list, a_ /; #/2 < a < #] & /@ list
```

> {{}, {2}, {3}, {5}, {9}, {9, 13}, {13, 14}, {14, 23}, {23,    27},
> {41}, {41, 67}, {67, 81}}

```
Length@Cases[list, a_ /; #/2 < a < #] & /@ list
```

> {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5):

```
list={2,3,5,9,13,14,23,27,41,67,81,99};

Map[Count[Thread[#/2<list<#],True]&,list]
(* {0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2} *)
```

See [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [`Count`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Count), [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread).

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) (not sure this is a good idea in terms of speed, ease of writing or legibility but it can be a good exercise)

For the purpose of illustration consider a smaller list:

```
test = list[[1 ;; 4]]
```

$$\{2,3,5,9\}$$

For each element in the list we make a comparison with all the other elements in the list. That is similar to the idea behind `Outer`. To show this illustratively consider the code below with a formal undefined function `g`:

```
Outer[g, test, test]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 g(2,2) & g(2,3) & g(2,5) & g(2,9) \\
 g(3,2) & g(3,3) & g(3,5) & g(3,9) \\
 g(5,2) & g(5,3) & g(5,5) & g(5,9) \\
 g(9,2) & g(9,3) & g(9,5) & g(9,9) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now consider reading the table above from top to bottom and consider g to be a question/criteria that takes two inputs and outputs true or false.

First line starting from right to left:

- does 9 satisfy the criteria by 2 ?
- does 5 satisfy the criteria by 2 ?
- does 3 satisfy the criteria by 2 ?
- does 2 satisfy the criteria by 2 ?

Second line from right to left :

- does 9 satisfy the criteria by 3 ?
- does 5 satisfy the criteria by 3 ?
- ...

Ok, so maybe you might want to take a pause to consider which criteria we could take for your purpose.

.

.

.

You can consider :

```
Outer[#1/2 < #2 < #1 &, test, test]
```

then you can count the number of True's in each line:

```
Count[True] /@ Outer[#1/2 < #2 < #1 &, test, test]
```

With the full list:

```
Count[True] /@ Outer[#1/2 < #2 < #1 &, list, list]
```

`(* {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2} *)`

---

**Edit**

Along a similar idea using [`Distribute`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html), [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html), [`Identity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Identity.html) and [`Boole`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html) but maybe rather difficult to understand:

```
Distribute /@ Distribute[g[list, Total[f /@ list]], List] /. 
  f -> Identity /. g -> (Boole[#1/2 < #2 < #1] &)
```

`(* {0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2} *)`

Comment: Cool idea, but i need to check around 100.000 numbers like that, so i would prefer the faster codes. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

list = {2, 3, 5, 9, 13, 14, 23, 27, 41, 67, 81, 99};

With[{x = #}, Count[list, _?(x/2 < # < x &)]] & /@ list

(* {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2} *)
```

Or with a helper function

```
count[x_] := Count[list, _?(x/2 < # < x &)]

count /@ list

(* {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2} *)

% === %%%

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Table` and `Select`:

```
Table[Length@Select[list, list[[i]]/2 < # < list[[i]] &], {i, 1, Length[list]}]
(*{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(x|-> MapThread[Boole@Thread[#/2< x < #]&,{x}].ConstantArray[1,Length@x])@list


(* {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2} *)
```

where

```
list={2,3,5,9,13,14,23,27,41,67,81,99}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {2, 3, 5, 9, 13, 14, 23, 27, 41, 67, 81, 99};
```

Using `Table` and `Count`

```
Table[Count[a, x_ /; a[[i]]/2 < x < a[[i]]], {i, Length[a]}]
```

> {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}